# Как преобразовать дату из ISO в формат Cегодня, 19 Сен?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

Как преобразовать дату в формате ISO. например '2018-09-19T14:48:00.000Z'

в формат Сегодня, 19 Сен, 14:48 ? 
При помощи date-fns

Comment: Что не получается из того что написано в документации date-fns?

Comment: пытаюсь сделать так https://jsfiddle.net/8Lg40jwh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`isToday`](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.5/docs/isToday)
- [`isTomorrow`](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/isTomorrow)
- [`format`](https://date-fns.org/v1.28.0/docs/format)

```js
const date = '2018-09-19T14:48:00.000Z';
const prefix = dateFns.isToday(date)
                 ? 'Сегодня, '
                 : dateFns.isTomorrow(date)
                   ? 'Завтра, '
                   : '';
const formatted = prefix + dateFns.format(date, 'DD MMM, HH:mm');
console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.29.0/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо. а если на русском месяцы?

Comment: Там есть locale: ru посмотрите документацию